# Error creating SPFx with React JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

Getting below error while trying to create an SPFx project with ReactJS, but if I use NO JS Framework it works fine. I have updated the npm to version **6.14.7**, updated the @microsoft/SharePoint template as well. Please suggest

[image: Unexpected Error]

Answer (score 0):

Do you run the npm install command as prompted?

Could you share your SPFX creation process for further research?

**My project structure:**
[image]

Comment: Installed Node JS version 10.20.X, then `npm install yo gulp -g`, then `npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint`. then using yeoman utility created a project with react framework `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: Ok, I am now doing a fresh installation...

Comment: Is it still wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is showing the same error again

Comment: This is strange. Could you share your project structure screenshot?

Comment: D:\SPFx Practices\deleteThis>npm list -g -depth 0
C:\Users\TejendraSingh\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- npm@6.14.7
+--  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\SPFxWithReact
+-- typescript@3.9.7
`-- yo@3.1.1

npm ERR! error in C:\Users\TejendraSingh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sp-fx-with-react: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\SPFxWithReact'

Comment: You could take look at:https://codedocu.com/Server/SharePoint/Error/Error-SharePoint-Gulp-Serve_colon_-Local-modules-not-found-in?2493